# Get a list of possible screen resolutions

Tags: c++, sfml, screen-resolution

Might have a "brain freeze" going on, but can't figure out how to get available screen resolutions in `SFML` and `C++`. Is there a function in `SFML` or do I need to code it myself?

Comment: `VideoMode::GetDesktopMode()` will get you the current screen resolution.

Answer (score 4):

## [static const std::vector& sf::VideoMode::getFullscreenModes()](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.0/classsf_1_1VideoMode.php#a6815b9b3b35767d5b4563fbed4bfc67b):

> **static const std::vector&
> sf::VideoMode::getFullscreenModes()** static
>
> Retrieve all the video modes supported in fullscreen mode.
>
> When creating a fullscreen window, the video mode is restricted to be
> compatible with what the graphics driver and monitor support. This
> function returns the complete list of all video modes that can be used
> in fullscreen mode. The returned array is sorted from best to worst,
> so that the first element will always give the best mode (higher
> width, height and bits-per-pixel).
>
> Returns Array containing all the supported fullscreen modes